# How can i change the method so it will create a bitmap image white on black background?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"I:\test\Untitled3.jpg"););
Bitmap GrayScaleBitmap = GrayScale(bitmap);
```

And the method GrayScale:

```
private Bitmap GrayScale(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        //get image dimension
        int width = bmp.Width;
        int height = bmp.Height;

        //color of pixel
        System.Drawing.Color p;

        //grayscale
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                //get pixel value
                p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                //extract pixel component ARGB
                int a = p.A;
                int r = p.R;
                int g = p.G;
                int b = p.B;

                //find average
                int avg = (r + g + b) / 3;

                //set new pixel value
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a, avg, avg, avg));
            }
        }

        return bmp;
    }
```

This is the original image i did for testing in paint:

[image]

And the result i'm getting as GrayScale:

[image]

The red shapes are now black on white background.
But instead i want the red shapes to be white on black background, and that's what i'm not sure how to change in the GrayScale method.

Comment: This question is a moving, hardly salvageable target.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct for grayscale.

What you want is a combination of grayscale and inversion.

Given that RGB operates in the scale of [0 - 255], you need to use that to reverse the current colors. I would suggest the following change;

`int avg = 255 - ((r + g +b) / 3)`

Which should achieve what you're after.

To illustrate why this works;
White is 255, 255, 255
Black is 0, 0, 0

So 255 - ((255 + 255 + 255) / 3) = 0 (i.e. white becomes black).

Comment: _"What you're doing is correct for grayscale"_ -- that's debatable. The algorithm will calculate a valid gray color for a given RGB color. But from a human perception point of view, the OP's implementation is _not_ correct. That is, a true "grayscale" image is simply the luminosity values as perceived by the human eye of the various colors, and that is _not_ a straight average of the three RGB components. Granted, this error on the OP's and your parts does not affect the overall question in terms of reversing the sense of the calculation, but IMHO it's important to understand the wrong code.

Comment: Ok i tested it again what i need is to get that the background will be white and the shape i draw to be black. Even if i draw in paint background in yellow and shape in brown the final result should be white background and black shapes.

Comment: Your question says "...white on black background." Which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the background to be white and the shape I draw to be black.

To achieve this, transform your `avg` (grayscale) value to 0 / 1 and multiply by 255.

```
//find white-black value
int bw = (r + g + b) / 384; // or /3 / 128 if you prefer
//set new pixel value
bmp.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a, bw*255, bw*255, bw*255));
```

Which gives you a pure black-and-white image:

[image]

> Even if I draw .. a brown shape on a yellow background the final
>   result should be black shapes on a white background.

My suggested approach covers this requirement but some sort of a "[threshold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fyk29fDmG4k)" (like in Photoshop, for example) is necessary for some hues.

```
int threshold = 128; // [1-254]
//find avg value [0-255]
int wb = (r + g + b) / 3;
//transform avg to [0-1] using threshold
wb = (wb >= threshold) ? 1 : 0;
//set new pixel value
bmp.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a, wb*255, wb * 255, wb * 255));
```

If the threshold is too small your result will be all white or if the threshold is too large all black. On borderline cases, you also may get distorted shapes/background (similar to an image editor when the hue/threshold does not fit). The value 128 separates the colorspace evenly (as my original algorithm did).

Some examples with a too low threshold:

A: Using threshold 70 with input brown on yellow.

[image]

B: Using threshold 60 with input brown on yellow.
[image]

Full source code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;    

namespace BwImgSO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C: \Users\me\Desktop\color.jpg");
            Bitmap grayScaleBitmap = GrayScale(bitmap);
            string outputFileName = @"C: \Users\me\Desktop\bw.jpg";
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    grayScaleBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        private static Bitmap GrayScale(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            //get image dimension
            int width = bmp.Width;
            int height = bmp.Height;
            int threshold = 128;

            //color of pixel
            System.Drawing.Color p;

            //grayscale
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    //get pixel value
                    p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                    //extract pixel component ARGB
                    int a = p.A;
                    int r = p.R;
                    int g = p.G;
                    int b = p.B;

                    //find average, transform to b/w value
                    //int bw = (r + g + b) / 3 / 128; // or 384 if you prefer
                    int wb = (r + g + b) / 3; // avg: [0-255]
                    //transform avg to [0-1] using threshold
                    wb = (wb >= threshold) ? 1 : 0;  
                    //set new pixel value
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a, bw*255, bw*255, bw*255));
                }
            }

            return bmp;
        }
    }
}
```